# Sitecore CMS - Domain per language

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I have a Sitecore CMS website. What I need is to host it in IIS for different domains (like www.company.de, www.company.com, www.company.se).

When user access website it should be accessible in language related to domain (com - english, de - german, etc.)

What is the best approach to achieve this? Is Sitecore multisite good for this case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A multisite content tree has to do with separate content. If you have the same content but in different context languages, you can have a single site in your tree and just setup your hostnames and `<site>` nodes in your config to use the right hostname and language. Multiple sites in the tree is useful for separate content on those separate hostnames.